# Find '1' in column C, return value from that row in column A

Tags: excel, lookup

[image: Screenshot from excel]

Hi, I'm trying to do some data analysis of some test results. I've got a section of my spreadsheet which essentially ranks each pupil's performance on that question.

In cell C57 I want to look for the smallest value in range C40:C55 (e.g. '1') and return the value from column B which corresponds to that row (in this example, C51).

Similarly, in C58 I want to find the second lowest value in the C40:C55 range (e.g '2') and return the corresponding B column value.

If I use VLOOKUP will I have the issue that a) my column with the '1' in is not the leftmost and, b) that my data are not listed in order?

Also, will I have an issue if there are two '1's in that column?

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to find with respect to the **first** 1:

=INDEX(A40:A55,MATCH(1,C40:C55,0))

For example:

[image]